# Does inserting a bit at a given position in binary numbers have a standard name?

Tags: algorithm, binary, numbers

I am writing an algorithm and I am using this two functions

```
/* add a zero at position k */
add0 k n = (n / (2 ^ k)) * (2 ^ (k + 1)) + (n mod (2 ^ k)).
/* add a one at position k */
add1 k n = (n / (2 ^ k)) * (2 ^ (k + 1)) + (2 ^ k) +  (n mod (2 ^ k)).
```

and its converse operation

```
/* remove the kth bit */
rm k n =  (n / (2 ^ (k + 1))) * (2 ^ k) + (n mod (2 ^ k)).
```

I was wondering if there are standard names for these operations and if there are some algorithms that use some version of them.

Comment: Instead of division and mod I think using mask and shift would be better.

Comment: @SomeDude yes the implementation could be smarter but here I wanted to explain simply what these functions do.

Comment: To `set` a bit, the typical way is to shift a `1` to the correct position and perform a bitwise `OR`.  To `clear` a bit, one can shift a `1` as before, invert and perform a bitwise `AND`.

Comment: yes I agree but does this operation has a standard name

Comment: The names I am aware of are `set` and `clear` or `reset`.

Comment: I am not sure. Did you notice it changes the number of bits : `add 3 (2 ^5) = 2^6`. So it is not just about setting or clearing but also about inserting.

Comment: It's like inserting a value into a bit list. But I don't know any algorithm that would need this, usually you add numbers at the front or back and shift (e.g. multiplication how it is learned in school).

Comment: The insert/delete operations that you describe are not very common at the bit level. They often occur in algorithms that manipulate arrays, and they're just called "insert" and "delete".